# Minimum Independence Assumptions needed for statement to be true?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I am a bit confused on conditional independence:

Given the following independence assumptions: ⫫, ⫫, ⫫, ⫫|, ⫫|,⫫|

What is the minimal set of independence assumptions needed in order for the equation to be true?

(a) (,) = (|)()

If we know that (,) = (|Y)(), then it must be the case that (|)=(|Y). I am confused as to how knowing conditional probabilities will help with this?

(b) (|) = (|)()
Again with this one I know that ()(|) = (,)P(x). Is there any information about X and Y being independent?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use Latex for math notation here.

Comment: The comment above regarding LaTeX is referring to the implementation of [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). Please learn it for your own good.